# Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have one dataframe (df1) like the following:

```
     ATime           ETime     Difference
0   1444911017815         1588510  1444909429305
1   1444911144979         1715672  1444909429307
2   1444911285683         1856374  1444909429309
3   1444911432742         2003430  1444909429312
4   1444911677101         2247786  1444909429315
5   1444912444821         3015493  1444909429328
6   1444913394542         3965199  1444909429343
7   1444913844134         4414784  1444909429350
8   1444914948835         5519467  1444909429368
9   1444915840638         6411255  1444909429383
10  1444916566634         7137240  1444909429394
11  1444917379593         7950186  1444909429407
```

I have another very big dataframe (df2) which has a column named **Absolute_Time**. **Absolute_Time** has the format as **ATime** of df1. So what I want to do is, for example, for all **Absolute_Time**'s that lay in the range of row 0 to row 1 of **ETime** of df1, I want to subtract row 0 of **Difference** of df1 and so on.

Comment: I do not understand the explanation of what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and we will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt to accomplish what you might be looking for, starting with:

```
print(df1)

            ATime    ETime     Difference
0   1444911017815  1588510  1444909429305
1   1444911144979  1715672  1444909429307
2   1444911285683  1856374  1444909429309
3   1444911432742  2003430  1444909429312
4   1444911677101  2247786  1444909429315
5   1444912444821  3015493  1444909429328
6   1444913394542  3965199  1444909429343
7   1444913844134  4414784  1444909429350
8   1444914948835  5519467  1444909429368
9   1444915840638  6411255  1444909429383
10  1444916566634  7137240  1444909429394
11  1444917379593  7950186  1444909429407
```

next creating a new `DataFrame` with random times within the range of `df1`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Absolute Time':[randrange(start=df1.ATime.iloc[0], stop=df1.ATime.iloc[-1]) for i in range(100)]})
df2 = df2.sort_values('Absolute Time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

`np.searchsorted` provides you with the `index positions` where `df2` should be inserted in `df1` (for the `columns` in question):

```
df2.index = np.searchsorted(df1.ATime.values, df2.loc[:, 'Absolute Time'].values)
```

Assigning the new index and merging produces a new `DataFrame`. Filling the missing `Difference` values forward allows to subtract in the next step:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left').fillna(method='ffill').dropna().astype(int)
df['Absolute Time Adjusted'] = df['Absolute Time'].sub(df.Difference)
print(df.head())

           ATime    ETime     Difference  Absolute Time  \
1  1444911144979  1715672  1444909429307  1444911018916   
1  1444911144979  1715672  1444909429307  1444911138087   
2  1444911285683  1856374  1444909429309  1444911138087   
3  1444911432742  2003430  1444909429312  1444911303233   
3  1444911432742  2003430  1444909429312  1444911359690   

   Absolute Time Adjusted  
1                 1589609  
1                 1708780  
2                 1708778  
3                 1873921  
3                 1930378
```